# Adopted Storage crashes phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

Using my app-lite Bush SPIRA B3 5(Android 6.0
1, not rooted) I created a 4Gb Adopted SD just for Google play music (and Messenger.) However, It can't get even a quarter full before my device crashes and flatly refuses to boot- Unless I Remove the SD. Any help?

Comment: Maybe you done something wrong? How did you created adoptable storage? Put an SD card into PC or other phone and format it, it should work then but as external

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Formatted through the phone. Twice. It's over Multiple SD cards too (Ack)